# Accessibility validation in visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, wcag

Visual studio 2013 has its own accessibility validation, to check the accessibility one has to click on the tools menu, then click Check Accessibility, my question is: it is possible to make this validation automatically with MSbuild or with another tool? 
Thanks

I need to check websites (MVC projects)

Answer (score 2):

You may also want to look at tenon.io (http://tenon.io/), they have an extension for VS2013.

Tenon differentiates from all the other tools by providing an API which can be leveraged to integrate automated testing in to the development process.

Karl Groves says it better than I could:

> All of my projects use Grunt, ... Tenon automatically performs unit testing on its own code. When something goes wrong, Grunt stops and yells at you. You can even tie Grunt to pre-commit hooks. In such a workflow nothing goes live without all your Grunt tasks running successfully.
>   Imagine, an enterprise-wide tool that can be used in each phase, that works directly as part of your existing workflows and toolsets. Imagine tying such a tool to everything from the very lowest level tasks all the way through to the build and release cycles and publication of content. That’s why I created Tenon.
>   While Tenon has a web GUI, the web GUI is actually a client application of the real Tenon product. In fact, internally Asa and I refer to and manage Tenon as a series of different things: Tenon Admin, Tenon UI, and Tenon (the API). The real deal, the guts, the muscle of the whole thing is the Tenon API which allows direct command line access to testing your code.

The beauty of Tenon is that because it is essentially an API, it can plug in to anything, Sublime, Webstorm, Netbeans, Notepad (probably not), Visual Studio!

Tenon.io Visual Studio add-on, compatible with 2013/2015 and 2013 Community Edition
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2015/03/03/improving-html-accessibility-with-visual-studio-extensions.aspx

The only catch, it’s not free for corporate users and it’s in the cloud (unless you pay Enterprise pricing for a local install). Pricing info: http://www.tenon.io/pricing.php

Karl Groves writes about his motivation for creating Tenon: http://www.karlgroves.com/2014/03/13/everything-you-know-about-accessibility-testing-is-wrong-part-4/

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the AccChecker Console

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj191809(v=vs.85).aspx

If you want API access to this you should read AccChecker API

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj191808(v=vs.85).aspx

Overview here:

UI Accessibility Checker

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh920985(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thank you, but i need to check websites and looks like AccChecker is for mobile and desktop apps.

Answer (score 0):

The closer solution I have found so far regarding this topic is in Visual Studio 2015 by adding the **Web Accessibility Checker** extension from Mads Kristensen, which is also free. The extension can be found at the [Visual Studio Marketplace website](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/). You can see the usage instructions within the description of the extension. This is an example of what you get once build the solution and tap on the Error List panel:

[image]

I hope can help.